# Is there a way to prevent ActiveRecord from loading one Model's attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a 'Polygon' Model in my Rails 6 app. It has 'geography' as one of its attributes (a representation of a georreferenced area), which is an RGeo object within Rails and a geography column from PostGIS.

I have a 'Rule' Model which is associated to 'Polygon' through a 'many-to-many' relation (model 'Spatial_Domain).

Whenever a Rule object is created or updated, Rails loads all its associated Polygons before commiting to my Postgresql database. I found out that loading the RGeo object in the 'geography' column of my polygons table takes a lot of time because the polygons are big and complex. So I tried this solution
https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter/issues/187#issuecomment-286278821
, which improved the response time quite a lot, but it still takes my app up to 70 seconds to complete 'create' and 'update' tasks.

So here I resume my question: is there a way to prevent ActiveRecord from loading the 'geography' attribute? (I only need ActiveRecord to create this attribute in the corresponding table during migration through the gem active-record-postgis).

Currently, my app does not require RGeo to do computations over 'geography' within Rails because the necessary ones are made from within the database.

Comment: You can limit which attributes are selected from the database by using `Model.select(:list, :of, :attributes)`. You could then add this as a default_scope if you truly never wish to have this column loaded from within rails

Comment: @StefanRendevski

Comment: is this what you were looking for?